# Assigning a value with echo piped together with the bc command and using a variable as an argument

Tags: bash, bash-script

Basically i'd like to assign to variable $finalbyte a value (which consists of a binary representation of a byte e.g 11100000). So trying to do that i put the following as part of some script:

```
field4=224     ##224 for example, it could be any number.
               ##Depends on the script

finalbyte=$(echo 'obase=2; ibase=10; ${field4}' | bc)   ##<-------error here
```

I get the following error which is kinda like obvious to interpret but my problem is that i don't know or imagine the way that $field4 could nestle down there in between the other arguments . The error is:

```
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: $
```

Comment: I consider your question as typo in using "${field4}" variable. When you use 'this' quotes , contents is not interpreted. If you use "this" quotes , contents is interpreted.

Additionally I would put whole $(...) into brackets finalbyte="$(...)".

Finally, I consider this question as not good fit for unix.se as it's about too basic problem - typo - of syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use double-quotes instead of single-quotes. Parameters are not substituted inside single-quotes

```
 finalbyte=$(echo "obase=2; ibase=10; ${field4}" | bc)
```

Also, if you are on bash, you may prefer here-strings to command substitution for this case:

```
bc <<<"obase=2; ibase=10; ${field4}"
```

Comment: Don't need triple quotes in bash. You have a leading empty string, the bc script and then a trailing empty string.

Answer (score 2):

move your variable outside of the quoted arg to echo:

```
$ field4=224 finalbyte=$(echo 'obase=2; ibase=10;' ${field4}| bc )
$ echo $finalbyte
11100000
```